# When does a linear ODE reach boundary?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an affine ODE
$$\frac{d}{d t} y(t) = Ay(t) + b$$
where $A$ is a known square matrix and $b$ is a known vector. I rewrite this equation in homogeneous coordinates as
$$\frac{d}{d t} \tilde{y}(t) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} A & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} y \\ 1\end{array} \right) = \tilde{A} \tilde{y}$$

Then I can solve the equation as
$$\tilde{y}(t) = expm( \tilde{A}t ) \tilde{y}_0$$

I have defined the original equation on a box in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\mathcal{B} = [a, b] \times [c, d]$.

My question is if there is a known expression for when the solution to the ODE hits the boundary of the box?

Comment: the solutions of linear equation live on $(-\infty, \infty);$  they only reach the boundary at $t = \pm \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the box $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ refers to restrictions on the dependent vector quantity $\vec y$ rather than say a space-time region?
If so, here are some suggestions that you might pursue.

1. Off hand I would suggest first analyzing the special case where $A$ is placed in diagonalized form. This special case merits detailed study because it is (generically) possible to achieve by a suitable linear change of the dependent variables (finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$).
   Such a change of variables converts the box to a parallelogram. 
   You will also see that by translating the dependent coordinates (an affine change of coordinates), the constant vector $\vec b$ can be suppressed in the transformed equations.
2. When the system has been diagonalized the system of differential equations decouple, and they can be solved in many ways (e.g. by separation of variables and direct one-variable integration).  In any case, it is the standard exponential growth equation.
3. The last messy step is working out the algebra of when the solution departs the distorted box (parallelogram).

4.I anticipate that another additional major complication will be that the signs of the diagonal entries of $A$ will affect your answer. It also seems unlikely that a universal formula will cover the cases when the square matrix  $A$ fails to become diagonalizable.